# how to acces output of CrossTable

Tags: r

I have the following output from `CrossTable`

```
             | predict 
      actual |       bad |      good | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
         bad |       412 |       188 |       600 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        good |       149 |       451 |       600 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |       561 |       639 |      1200 | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

and I need to assign output to indivial variable like
a1<-412
a2<-451  and so on   how can I do it ?

Comment: We fixed your formatting, but in the future please indent fixed-width blocks like tables and code with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

CrossTable produces that screen output as a "service" for users of SAS and SPSS who are used to it. The `table` function is what "real useRs" would use and it delivers a table object that can be assessed via standard indexing:

```
with( dfrm, table(actual, predict)[1,1] )  # should be "a1" = 412
```

Assuming this is `gmodels::CrossTable` the help page tells you that the value returned is a list for which the `t` node is a similar matrix so this should succeed:

```
 with( dfrm, CrossTable(actual, predict)$t[1,1]) # should be "a1" = 412
```

The proportions tables have different names. Read the Value section of `?CrossTable`. Looking at the help page for `descr::CrossTable` it appears, it has done things a bit differently but has retained that structure and names in the value returned.

Comment: I have an error:Error in with(dfrm, table(actual, predict)[1, 1]) : 
  object 'dfrm' not found
>

Comment: CrossTable(yield_test$Quality,yield_boost_50,,prop.r=F,prop.c=F,prop.t=F,prop.chisq=F,dnn=c('actual','predict'))

Comment: what would be a dfrm ?

Comment: Since you failed to include a reproducible example I just posted some code with the assumption it would be applied to a data.frame with the name 'dfrm' that  had column names 'actual' and 'predicted'. If you have an appropriate dataframe with the name 'yield_test' then it appeared to have the column.names 'predict' and 'actual'. If you did some sort of tabulation to produce an object where `yield_test$Quality,` was a dataframe or matrix, then consider editing your question to include output from `dput(yield_test$Quality,)`

Comment: I did it, unfortunately output too big..can't fi it here

Comment: I really appreciate your help !!!   Is it possible to send you e-mail output of dput(yield_test$Quality) , but the last line

Comment: NA, NA), .Label = c("bad", "good"), class = "factor")
>  
>   a1<-with( yield_test$Quality, table(actual, predict)[1,1] )
Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
>

Comment: Post the output of `dput(yield_test$Quality)` in a dropbox.